# How can alter the values of a composite type column inside trigger function before insert?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which has the following columns:

1. inspireId **type : inspireid** (composite type)
2. gid **type : integer** (primary key)

The inspireId column type is as following :

```
CREATE TYPE inspireId AS (
  nameSpace text,
  local_id integer
)
```

I want to fill local_id automatically with the value of gid when creating a new row in the table.

I tried the following :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION script.addLocalId() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
    BEGIN
        NEW."inspireId".local_id := NEW.gid;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But this is not working. The following error is thrown when creating the trigger function:

> «new.inspireId.local_id» is not a known variable.

What is the right syntax for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [access composite array elements plpgsql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39029020/access-composite-array-elements-plpgsql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not directly access to type element.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION script.addLocalId() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
    BEGIN
        NEW."inspireId" = ((NEW.inspireId).nameSpace, NEW.gid)::inspireId;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION script.addLocalId() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
    SELECT (
         'any value for nameSpace ', 
          NEW.gid
    )::inspireId INTO NEW.inspireId;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```