# Assigning values to composite array elements

Tags: postgresql

I have created a type as below.

```
create type test_typ as (id int, nam text, age int);
```

I created an array of the type test_typ and tried to assign values to each element as below

```
do
$$
declare
tt test_typ[];
begin
tt[1].id = 1;
tt[1].nam = 'sds';
tt[1].age = 23;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

I get syntax error when I do the above. But when I do the below and tried to print `tt[1].id`, it prints the value correctly.

```
do
$$
declare
tt test_typ[];
begin
tt[1] := (1,'sds',23);
raise notice '%', tt[1].id;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Why is not getting assigned with `tt[1].id`, `tt[1].nam`, `tt[1].age` while it prints if I try the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT) :

> The target variable can be a simple variable (optionally qualified with a block name), a field of a row or record variable, or an element of an array that is a simple variable or field.

So it seems that arrays of composite types are not supported in assignment operation.

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39029020/access-composite-array-elements-plpgsql) answered by Pavel Stehule you might find helpfull.